# Can't resolve heap corruption at runtime

Tags: c, pointers, heap-corruption

I'm writing a program that reads from a text file and try to create a structure dynamically.

So I have the following code to do that:

```
typedef struct tgraph {
    int vertex_count;
    int edge_count;
    struct tvertex **adj;
} Graph;

typedef struct tvertex {
    int n; /* vertex number */
    char course[255];
    struct tvertex *next;
} Vertex;

Graph g_graph;

void create_graph(FILE *fd) 
{
    int vertex_count;
    int edge_count; 
    fscanf(fd, "%i", &vertex_count);
    fscanf(fd, "%i", &edge_count);
    printf("Vertices: %i\n", vertex_count);
    printf("Edges: %i\n", edge_count);
    g_graph.vertex_count = vertex_count;
    g_graph.edge_count = edge_count;
    g_graph.adj = malloc(sizeof(Vertex *));
    Vertex **vlist = g_graph.adj;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < vertex_count; i++) {
        Vertex *vertex = malloc(sizeof(Vertex));
        fscanf(fd, "%i,%[^\n]", &vertex->n, vertex->course);
        printf("%i %s\n", vertex->n, vertex->course);
        *vlist = vertex;
        vlist ++;;
    }
}
```

I'm calling this function `create_graph` and getting this error at runtime

> corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000007d7240

This is caused in  the main function by a call to `fclose(fd)`. I know that the problem is that I am corrupting the heap. My pointer arithmetic is probably wrong but I'm not able to solve it.

I'm compiling with gcc at linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line `g_graph.adj = malloc(sizeof(Vertex *))` only allocates space for one `Vertex` pointer. As soon as you do `vlist++`, you move into unallocated space, and any use of that space is undefined.

You'll need to change that first malloc call to `malloc(sizeof(Vertex *) * vertex_count)` to properly allocate the space.

Comment: Great, it worked! Thanks, I was tailing something like that but I was not sure and it was not clear to me. Your answer cleared me out.